# Puzzle: what's wrong with this snippet

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

... and how did it happen (guessing allowed, of course :-)

```
@Override
public int convertChildIndexToModel(int modelIndex) {
    return getRowSorter() != null ? getRowSorter()
            .convertRowIndexToView(modelIndex) : modelIndex;
}

@Override
public int convertChildIndexToView(int viewIndex) {
    return getRowSorter() != null ? getRowSorter()
            .convertRowIndexToModel(viewIndex) : viewIndex;
}
```

and yeah, the idiot was me ;-)

Comment: Runner up: [*spontaneous symmetry breaking*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking). :-)

Comment: @trashgod disagree I think that [9 or 10th. song by Nena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/99_Luftballons_%28album%29)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

calling `convertRowIndexToView` with `modelIndex` and vice-versa. Must be some copy-paste bug :)

Comment: +1 and accepted for the quickest :-)

Answer (score 3):

Is it because you should be calling `convertRowIndexToModel` in `convertChildIndexToModel` and vice versa?

Comment: exactly spotted the error :-)